# asp.net core form tag helpers: attributes started with @ are discarded

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm migrating an existing .NET 4.7 MVC app to ASP.NET Core and one of the things I'm doing is replacing the old helpers with the new tag helpers. Now, it seems like the new form tag helper will simply discard all attributes that start with @:

```
<form asp-action="Ficha" asp-controller="Utilizador" method="post" @@submit="grava">
```

The idea is to generate an HTML form element which looks like this:

```
<form action="Utlizador/Ficha" method="post" @submit="grava">
```

The @submit handle is being consumed by an existing Vuejs client (shortcut for handling the form's submit event).

Btw, my previous code (in the existing .NET MVC app) looked like this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Ficha", "Utilizador")" method="post" @@submit="grava">
```

I know that replacing it with the long form (v-on:) does work, but is there a way to make the form helper output the @submit attribute from the server side?

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: Have you tried @("@submit=\"grava\"")  ?

Comment: Hello Jason. Yes, same result though...

Comment: How's about @Html.Raw("@submit=\"grava\"") ?

Comment: You might want to open an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/Razor. I’ve looked through the issues and the `@` has always been a problematic character with tag helpers but there doesn’t appear to be an issue about attribute names starting with it yet.

Comment: I've ended up adding a new issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2441

Comment: Created a new issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31640 after the original one was closed.